# Netlogo: How to compare the ID and then flag in this case?

Tags: netlogo, flags

I would like to put a flag called "min-id" for the turtle with the smallest ID. And I want to flag other turtles as "not-min-id". However the following sample syntax has errors. The error message is as follows.

" error while turtle 0 running >
  called by procedure GO
  called by button 'go' "

I probably to need your advice. Thank you.

```
globals [ min-id not-min-id count-up ID ]

to go
  reset-ticks

  ask patch 0 0 
  [
    sprout 1 ;;This model needs to use sprout.
  ]

  ask (turtles-on patch 0 0)
  [
    set ID who
    setxy min-pxcor 0
    set heading 90
  ]

  if (count turtles > 0)
    [
      ask min-one-of turtles [who]
      [
        set min-id TRUE
      ]
  ]

  if (count turtles > 0)
    [
      ask (turtles-on patch 0 0)
      [
        if ID > min-one-of turtles [who] ;;This syntax has errors.
        [
          set not-min-id TRUE
        ]
      ]
  ]  

  ask (turtles-on patch 0 0) with [not-min-id]
  [
    set count-up count-up + 1
  ]

  if (count turtles > 0) [
    ask (turtles-on patch 0 0) with [min-id]
    [
      die
    ]

    tick
end
```

Comment: `ID` is a number but if `min-one-of turtles [who]` is a turtle.  More generally, when you find yourself working with `who`, you should usually refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some confusion in your code. From your description, I believe you want each turtle to have a flag for whether or not it has the minimum who number. This means you need a flag for each turtle. However, you have set up min-id as a global variable instead of a turtle variable. Furthermore, you only need the flag variable once (that is, you need min-id but not not-min-id) and you set it to TRUE or FALSE.

Replace

```
globals [ min-id not-min-id count-up ID ]
```

with

```
globals [ count-up ID ]
turtles-own [ min-id ]
```

and see if that fixes it. Also initialise min-id to FALSE as part of the `sprout`.

Having said all that, I strongly agree with Alan, if you ever use the `who` variable for anything except print statements in debug, you probably need to rethink your code. In your case, what is special about the turtle with the lowest `who` number that makes you want to keep track of it? Do you simply want a random turtle that happens to be at a particular location? Then select a random turtle at that location to do the TRUE/FALSE without going through `who`.

Comment: It is helpful for setting flags and variables. Thank you very much.